# ' using on Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html-entities

```
<?php $text="Alice's";?>
```

($text data comes form database, I just put an example like Alice's)

```
<button  type="submit" onclick="Remove('<?php echo  $text; ?>')"></button>

<script>
Remove(text){
alert(text);
}
</script>
```

When I use ' at $text variable Javascript function Remove() does not work. I use php htmlentities() function but it does not work

Comment: Include the double quotes in JS, as the content already contains a single quote. ... Or rather drop the idea in the first place, inline event handlers are bad, and messing JS with PHP is even worse.

Comment: I could not understand your suggestions.

Comment: Take a look at the source code of your loaded page, then you'll understand the quoting mess in your code ...

Comment: `<?php echo  $text; ?>` evaluates to `"Alice's"`, and now your function is `Remove('Alice's')`. Can you see the problem now?

Comment: The simplest way to fix this is to escape the single quote for JS in PHP: `$text = "Alice\'s"`.

Comment: also $text comes from sql, I said that I tried php htmlentities().. I can not use \

Comment: Thanks but it does not work..

Comment: What "_does not work_"? `\ ` is not a HTML entity, it's an escape character, and it "works" perfectly when I put it on my local server and load a page. You can also use a string template to enclose the PHP part instead of single quotes: `onclick="Remove(\`<?=$text?>\`);"`

Comment: You just wrote this about using escape character: "Remove(\"<?php echo  $text; ?>\")" This is not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is because once your string is passed into the onClick function it is getting confused with all the `'` and `"`.

So to make this work you could escape your variable `'` with a `\`
Depending where the data is coming from you may need to write something that escapes these automatically for you.

```
<?php $text="Alice\'s"; ?>

<button  type="submit" onclick="Remove('<?php echo  $text; ?>')"></button>


<script>
    function Remove(text){
        alert(text);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but $text data is coming from database. I just write it to show the problem. So I think I can not edit data like yours :  $text="Alice\'s";

Comment: If your data is coming from somewhere else you could try putting it through `addslashes()` function in PHP first. 

For example: 
`<?php
$str = "Alice's";

$text = addslashes($str);
?>
`

Here's the docs for it: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Comment: When I used addslashes() funciton. It seem like that <button  type="submit"onclick="Remove('Alice\'s')">fff</button>

 and Does not work again

Comment: This example works on mine, what's the error it gives you? 
Is your document a .PHP of .HTML ?

Comment: It is a php file

Comment: Here is a working example of it (it's using `console.log` instead of `alert`) Check the console it prints `Alice's `

https://www.tehplayground.com/3ZYFe3YO1zxoLdal

Comment: This example and the example you have just sent is working however the playground blocks `alert()` - check your console